# hex input to bitset<64> C++

Tags: c++, hex, bitset

Can anyone explain why the following does not work for me please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string tempString;
uint64_t tempValue;

cout << "enter addr in hex : ";
cin >> tempString;
istringstream ost(tempString);
ost >> hex >> tempValue;
bitset<64>  addr(tempValue);
cout << "addr = " << addr << endl;
}
```

Only the lowest 32 bits of the bitset are set correctly.  The highest bits remain 0.  I have tried also using unsigned long long in place of uint64_t.

I am using windows vista and the code::blocks editor which was only recently installed.

I have tried installing code::blocks onto another machine I have running windows xp and the problem is the same.

edit 2 --

I changed the code to the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string tempString;
uint64_t tempValue;

cout << "enter addr in hex : ";
cin >> tempString;
istringstream ost(tempString);
if (ost >> hex >> tempValue) cout << "ok" << endl; else cout << "bad" << endl;
ost >> hex >> tempValue;
cout << tempValue << endl;
bitset<64>  addr(tempValue);
cout << "addr = " << addr << endl;
}
```

and now when I input `ffffffffff` i get the output

```
ok
1099511627775
addr = 0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111
```

Thanks.

Comment: Works on my machine. What compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: Can you please show example input and output? And maybe check the value of `tempValue` too?

Comment: `if (ost >> hex >> tempValue) cout << "ok"; else cout << "bad";` What does this say if you try with your string?

Comment: Bad ram. and sunstorms.

Comment: I am using a windows vista machine, the compiler is whatever came with code::blocks.  It says GNU GCC compiler when I look in the settings.

Comment: the if statement says ok.

Comment: I would add a printout of the `tempValue` to see that it's correct.

Comment: fofofo? And that's acceepted? Not using zeros?

Comment: Is that the letter `o` in the input or the digit `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a C++03 compiler. In C++03, the `bitset` constructor takes an `unsigned long` parameter, which on your platform is 32 bits, so you lose the upper bits.

In C++11, this was changed to take an `unsigned long long`, so your code would have worked. It would also work on a platform where `long` is 64 bits.

You will need to use a different method to convert a 64-bit integer to a binary representation string or to a `std::bitset`, for example a loop going over all bits.

You can also construct the bitset in two parts:

```
set::bitset<64> bs = (std::bitset<64>(val >> 32) << 32)  | 
                     std::bitset<64>(val & 0xffffffff);
```